# Crystal Reports - Combine Rows

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm very new to Crystal Reports and I've one little problem.
I'll be quick and on point.

The columns are as follow:
2016-01-05, 2016-01-06, 2016-01-07, 2016-01-08, 2016-01-09 (list goes on till end of year)
These dates come from Database field called NextDueDate and it populates the report with all the dates.

My question, is it possible to combine these rows or group them by weeks or perhaps by month?

Result I'm looking for is:
2016-01 (All january days combined here) or something like maybe even just January etc.

NextDueDate field is type string by the way.
Also, I'd like to do this without getting involved in the actual database itself due to specific reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this simple formula as

@year_month = left ({NextDueDate},7);

[image]

create formula as year_month

and put `left ({NextDueDate},7);` in formula editor click on save.

[image]

now you can see this formula under formula field in field explorer.

Drag this one to your detailed section.
You can group the result based on this formula.

```
                    OR
```

user these formula

```
@year_month = left ({NextDueDate},7);
@monthOnly = right( @year_month , 2);
@FullMonthName = if @monthOnly = '01' then 'January'
                 else if {@month} = '02' then 'February'
                 ........................................
                 else 'December';
```

Comment: Hey ankur, As i've mentioned I'm quiet now to this. Could you possibly expand a bit more on your answer. I'd be very grateful. Thank You

Comment: i have added detailed steps hope it will help you to understand.. :)

Comment: I kind of understand what you're doing there but if I make the first formula all it will do is show the same results as it already does. Second formula in return gives me "Remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula". I've mentioned it is a string type and not date so I hope it doesn't affect your formula. I've also up-voted your answer, not visible due to me being under 15 rep.

Comment: Don't forget to apply group on that formula. After that only it combine these rows in to month.

Comment: Thanks a million ankur, it worked fine for me and I got the result I was looking for!